# Android Studio Library Project Not Generating Jar File

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, android-library

How do I build a JAR file from an Android Studio project? I've followed a lot of guides without much success. I tried compiling as a regular and library project but no JAR file get automatically generated. Do I have to do it manually or resort to Ant to get the Jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio will compile your library into an AAR not a JAR. AARs are a little different since we rely on the SDK rather than a JAR to give use the Android API.

You will find the AAR under `LibraryName/build/libs/LibraryName.aar`.

Comment: Also remember one thing this /libs directory will not be visible in Android Studio's project explorer. Search it in your project directory   on drive.